# What exactly do the blocks represent?

Tags: ruby

Absolute newbie at Ruby. I don't really understand the `|animal|` section. Can someone please explain it to me?

```
ark = ["Cat", "dog", "pig", "goat"]
ark.each do |animal|
    puts animal
end
```

Comment: see here http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-each. Read doc first, this is very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other languages the syntax may look something like this:

```
ark = ["Cat", "dog", "pig", "goat"];
ark.each(function (animal) { puts animal; });
```

Does that clear it up? It's the syntax for an anonymous function. If you're not familiar with that concept, how about this?

```
function putAnimal(animal) {
    puts animal;
}

ark = ["Cat", "dog", "pig", "goat"];
ark.each(putAnimal);
```

`|animal|` is the argument list for the anonymous function. Very roughly speaking, Ruby's syntax for the common `function (arg) { ... }` is `do |arg| ... end`.